# Why do nested views have a different explain plan than a single merged view?

Tags: sql, oracle, view, sql-execution-plan

I have a view `V2` that selects from another view `V1` and adds a couple predicate filters.

```
V2 IS SELECT * FROM V1 
WHERE ACTIVE='Y' 
AND TYPE = '1';
```

When I do a join between `V2` and a table `FOO` on the column `USER_ID` (indexed in `FOO`) I find that it first calculates the entire results for `V2` before joining with `FOO` on the indexed column (indexed also in the source table of `V1`).

```
SELECT * FROM FOO 
INNER JOIN V2
  ON FOO.USER_ID = V2.USER_ID
WHERE FOO.SCHOOL = '3'
```

But when I do a join between `V1` and `FOO` it finds the record in `FOO` first and then uses the index to quickly retrieve the row from `V1` using predicate pushing & indexes.

I have narrowed down the difference to the fact that `V2` is built on top of `V1` with predicates.  I changed `V2` to be an exact copy of `V1` but put the two additional predicate filters in it directly and found that it behaved the same way when joined with `FOO` that `V1` did but with the proper restrictions in place now.

Are nested views unable to push predicates all the way down to the tables?  Also, how consistent is predicate pushing?  I have several views where if predicates are not pushed it would ruin performance.  They work fine now but what guarantee is there they will continue to do so?

I'd like to nest/inherit views rather than duplicating the exact same queries with minor differences to keep things DRY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Oracle are you using?
What is the parameter [OPTIMIZER_SECURE_VIEW_MERGING](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams162.htm#REFRN10262) set to?  You may try setting that to FALSE or granting the user the MERGE ANY VIEW privilege.

If that doesn't help, can you post the two query plans?